# How to efficiently send large String to java selenium textarea element

Tags: java, performance, selenium, webdriver

I need to send Large text in the type of String to textArea element. I use

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(textarea_xpath)).sendKeys(fileText);
```

But Its too slow. Any ideas to make this fast?

Comment: How large is large? There's not really another way to send it unless you use straight JS but that probably won't be faster either. You could try sending smaller chunks of the text using `.sendKeys()` but that shouldn't go faster.

Comment: No Way. Selenium bahaves like this. typing will be very slow.

Comment: How about `ctrl+c` and `ctrl+v`, not sure if it will be bit faster or not.

Comment: @cruisepandey Yes  copying the content to the clipboard and the paste it in the textArea is faster then `sendKeys` in selenuim.  but the problem is that this willn't work once i use headless mode in the chrome driver

Comment: `element.sendKeys(String string)` takes approximately 8 seconds for string of leghth 10000 chars. Which is acceptable. How big is your string?

Comment: @pburgr My string is about 6000 chars so it takes about 5 seconds. but my problem is that in this project I will need to make this process as fast as possible. In about one second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it with JS executor:

```
  public void enterTextJS(By locator, String text) {
    JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(locator);
    jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].value='" + text + "';", element);
  }
```

Comment: Your code works only when text is one line string and fails when it is a multiline string So it will be better to use this instead `jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[1].value=arguments[0]", "'" + text + "'", element);`

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly same solution as Villa_7's.
Setting text of 6k chars takes ~ 25 miliseconds.

```
package selenium;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Random;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class OmarHafez extends WebDriverSetup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = startChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form");
        WebElement addressField = driver.findElement(By.tagName("textarea"));
        addressField.click();
        String s = randomStringOfLength(6000);
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now());
        String js = "document.evaluate(\"//textarea[@id='currentAddress']\", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.value = '" + s + "';";
        JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        javascriptExecutor.executeScript(js);
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now());
        System.out.println(addressField.getAttribute("value"));
        driver.quit();
    }
    
    public static String randomStringOfLength(int length) {
        int leftLimit = 48; // numeral '0'
        int rightLimit = 122; // letter 'z'
        Random random = new Random();
        String generatedString = random.ints(leftLimit, rightLimit + 1)
          .filter(i -> (i <= 57 || i >= 65) && (i <= 90 || i >= 97))
          .limit(length)
          .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
          .toString();
        return generatedString;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void enterTextJS(By locator, String text) 
{
    JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(locator);
    jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[1].value=arguments[0]", "'" + text + "'", element);}
```

This worked for me like a charm. For multiple lines of text, this is the best solution. Thanks @omar_Hafez